# python escape special characters

Tags: python, json

I am working on python project where I should consume JSON objects from Kafka.

Some fields in the JSON contain double quotes, \n, \r ...

When I try to convert the JSON to dict it fails as it is not a valid JSON.

Here is a sample of the JSON I am working with

```
{
  "id": "tag:search.twitter.com,2005:803149832814731264",
  "body": "RT @pnu_nourah: #دعوة من نادي قادة الصحة بكلية الصحة وعلوم التأهيل لحضور "الحملة التوعوية لسرطان الرئة " \n#جامعة_الأميرة_نورة\n#pnu "
}
```

Escaping the \n and \r is simple but the double quotes cause a problem as the field names and values are enclosed in double quotes also.

How could I escape the double quotes in the fields values only without affecting the other quotes.

I am using json library `json.loads(line)` to convert the json to dict.

I use regex like r'\"body\" : \"' but the problem may appear in other fields not just the body.

Comment: Can you show the code you have tried?

Comment: I removed all the fields from the json and kept only the field that contains the problem.

Comment: You need to show the code you have tried.

Comment: In a nutshell, your JSON is invalid JSON. Where does this JSON get generated? By Kafka? By some other process? Is that process perhaps getting confused with escaping RTL text correctly?

Comment: Can you post a complete, minimal and verifiable example, with expected output and any errors you are getting? It looks like you are trying to load invalid JSON as @deceze said. But we really can't tell without the code and error message.

Comment: If you've been given data that is invalid, I don't think there's a solution that's guaranteed to work. However you can find quotes that should *probably* be escaped if they are *not* immediately followed by appropriate characters, i.e. `{}[]",` (there are many possible combinations) and whitespace.

Comment: If you get broken json, then contact whoever is responsible for generating this broken json and ask them to fix their stuff.

Comment: How do you want to handle `{"a": "b", "c": "d"}`?  Is that one key or two?

Answer (score 1):

Use single quotes around keys and values (instead of double quotes ;).